# PHP Syntax Error Unexpected '}'

Tags: php

Newbie to PHP here. I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in ... on line 1

Below is the code and I'm having trouble finding this simple mistake. Can anybody help? This file is a file in wordpress thesis theme and is in PHP.

```
<?php

// Using hooks is absolutely the smartest, most bulletproof way to implement things like plugins,
// custom design elements, and ads. You can add your hook calls below, and they should take the
// following form:
// add_action('thesis_hook_name', 'function_name');
// The function you name above will run at the location of the specified hook. The example
// hook below demonstrates how you can insert Thesis' default recent posts widget above
// the content in Sidebar 1:
// add_action('thesis_hook_before_sidebar_1', 'thesis_widget_recent_posts');

// Delete this line, including the dashes to the left, and add your hooks in its place.

/**
 * function custom_bookmark_links() - outputs an HTML list of bookmarking links
 * NOTE: This only works when called from inside the WordPress loop!
 * SECOND NOTE: This is really just a sample function to show you how to use custom functions!
 *
 * @since 1.0
 * @global object $post
*/

function custom_bookmark_links() {
    global $post;
?>
<ul class="bookmark_links">
    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="http://delicious.com/save?url=<?php urlencode(the_permalink()); ?>&amp;title=<?php urlencode(the_title()); ?>" onclick="window.open('http://delicious.com/save?v=5&amp;noui&amp;jump=close&amp;url=<?php urlencode(the_permalink()); ?>&amp;title=<?php urlencode(the_title()); ?>', 'delicious', 'toolbar=no,width=550,height=550'); return false;" title="Bookmark this post on del.icio.us">Bookmark this article on Delicious</a></li>
</ul>
<?php
}

/*** HEADER AD WIDGET***/
register_sidebars(1,
array(
'name' => 'HeaderAd',
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s">',
'after_widget' => '</li>',
'before_title' => '<h3>',
'after_title' => '</h3>'
)
);
function header_widget() { ?>
<div id="header_widget_1">
<ul class="sidebar_list">
<?php thesis_default_widget(3); ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php }

add_action('thesis_hook_header', 'header_widget', '1');
/***  HEADER WIDGET END***/

/*remove footer attribution*/
remove_action('thesis_hook_footer', 'thesis_attribution');

function seth_godin_stuff_1 () {
if (is_single()) {
?>
<p class="alert" style="text-align:center;">Interested in a free 25+ eBook on the 7 Wastes? Please <a href="http://www.shmula.com/7-wastes-of-lean/">DOWNLOAD HERE</a>.</p>
<?php
}
}

add_action('thesis_hook_before_post', 'seth_godin_stuff_1', '1');

function single_post_ads() {
if (is_single()) { ?>
<BR>
<div align="center">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/06/1421749706.js"></script></td>
<td><a target="new" href="http://amzn.to/ddLMpa"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4151" title="the-toyota-way-ad-unit" src="http://www.shmula.com/http://www.shmula.com/wp-content/uploads/Image/2010/08/the-toyota-way-ad-unit.jpg" alt="" width="102" height="157" /></a></td>
<td><a target="new" href="http://amzn.to/9epSyC"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4152" title="the-toyota-way-fieldbook-ad-unit" src="http://www.shmula.com/http://www.shmula.com/wp-content/uploads/Image/2010/08/the-toyota-way-fieldbook-ad-unit.jpg" alt="" width="111" height="158" /></a></td>
<td><a target="new" href="http://amzn.to/ac4i1v"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4149" title="the-toyota-culture-ad-unit" src="http://www.shmula.com/http://www.shmula.com/wp-content/uploads/Image/2010/08/the-toyota-culture-ad-unit.jpg" alt="" width="98" height="161" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"><div align="center"><h5>This post was written by <a href="http://www.shmula.com/about-peter-abilla/" rel="author">Pete Abilla</a></h5>
</div></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<?php }
}

add_action('thesis_hook_after_post', 'single_post_ads');

remove_action('thesis_hook_after_post', 'thesis_post_tags');


/*social bookmarks right header*/
function thesis_header_ad() {
?>
<div id="banner_ad">
<div align="center">
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/shmula">
<img src="http://www.shmula.com/wp-content/uploads/image/social-icons/linkedin.jpg"
height="68" width="68" border="0" alt="" /></a>&nbsp; <a rel="nofollow" href="http://twitter.com/shmula">
<img src="http://www.shmula.com/http://www.shmula.com/wp-content/uploads/Image/2011/04/Twitter.png" height="70" width="70" border="0"
alt="follow shmula on twitter" /></a>&nbsp; <a rel="nofollow"
href="http://www.facebook.com/shmula">
<img src="http://www.shmula.com/http://www.shmula.com/wp-content/uploads/Image/2011/04/FaceBook.png"
height="70" width="70" border="0" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/shmula/dfYo">
<img src="http://www.shmula.com/http://www.shmula.com/wp-content/uploads/Image/2011/04/Feed.png"
height="70" width="70" border="0" alt="" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="http://forms.aweber.com/form/77/1324894377.htm">
<img src="http://www.shmula.com/wp-content/uploads/image/social-icons/Email.gif"
height="70" width="70" border="0" alt="" /></a>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}//end of php block

/* BEGIN Custom Widgetized Footer */
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {      

register_sidebar(array('name' => 'Footer Widget ', 'id' => 'footer-widget-', 'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">', 'after_widget' => '</div>', 'before_title' => '<h3>', 'after_title' => '</h3>'));}

function widgetized_footer() { ?><div id="widgetized_wrapper"> <?php 

  if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widget') ) : ?> 
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  <?php 
}

remove_action('thesis_hook_footer', 'thesis_attribution');add_action('thesis_hook_footer', 'widgetized_footer');
/* END Custom Widgetized Footer *//*footer widget*/

/*custom popular posts thumbnails*/
function pop_posts_with_thumbs() { ?>
    <li class="widget popular_posts">
        <h3>POPULAR POSTS</h3>
        <ul>
        <? $args = array('posts_per_page' => 28, 'orderby' => 'comment_count', 'category__in' => array(131,16,29,17,281,651,120,193,650,135,147,9,508,64,613,654,655));
        global $post;
        $popular = get_posts($args);
        foreach($popular as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail('thumb'); } ?><?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!--[if lte IE 6]>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            <![endif]-->
        <? } ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
<? }
add_action('thesis_hook_after_sidebar_1', 'pop_posts_with_thumbs');

/*thumbnail functions*/
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 610, 9999, true );
add_image_size( 'teaser', 150, 150, true );
add_image_size( 'thumb', 50, 50, true );

/*link rel for next/prev*/
add_action('wp_head', 'index_rel_link'); // Relational link for site index
add_action('wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link'); // Relational link for first post
add_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head'); // Relational links for adjacent posts
add_action('wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link'); // Relational link for parent item
```

Comment: I hope you are aware that this is *spaghetti code* ..

Comment: What sort of editor are you using? Does it support syntax checking? What sort of information are you getting there; or are you using Notepad?

Comment: BTW, search for `http://www.shmula.com/http://www.shmula.com/`, I think you'll be surprised how often it is in your code.

Comment: There are no syntax errors with the code you've posted. What's the rest of the error message? Are you certain you're posting the right file?

Comment: Spaghetti code, yes. And I'm using Notepad++. If you go to [link](http://www.shmula.com/), you'll see the error.

Comment: The error message should also contain a file path. Please double-check that you've posted the content of the exact file in question. There is no } on line 1 and no call to eval() in the code you've posted.

Comment: there's a chance the error is not in this file.. I saved your sample in a file and no syntax errors occurred... just some undefined functions (from wp) and after I created some dummy replacements the script ran fine to its end

Comment: @tereško: WordPress is all about spaghetti code.

Comment: http://www.shmula.com reports `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/content/35/3364535/html/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/custom_functions.php on line 1`

Comment: The exact error is found at http://www.shmula.com/ and the code above is from the right php file. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Please check the output of `<?php highlight_file('/home/content/35/3364535/html/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/custom_functions.php'); `

Comment: Okay, thankfully I was able to roll-back to a previous version so my site is back up now. But still, I have no idea what the root cause of the problem was. Thanks all for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

I added the missing functions. Now this code is running: http://codepad.org/mSjq2eE3

What ever the problem is. It is not visible here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your  tags are only at the beginning & end of your file, for starters. This code is kind of a mess. Was this how you found it in the template?

Comment: Yes, the template was like that already. I added some functions, but I removed those as I was debugging, but still I get the error, so the root cause wasn't my addition. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you PHP code has no syntax error. The error showing in line 1 is not in this code fragment. Since it is Wordpress, you might change some other part of theme, in another file and it is showing the error. Or you have some partially uploaded files in the server.